# Как создать класс для xml десериализации

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Есть `xml`. Как я понимаю делать элементы класса с атрибутами atr1, atr2... является неправильным, так как если их будет больше и с другими id, то придется создать еще много свойств.

```
<root>
   <tag atr1 = "value"/>
   <tag atr2 = "value"/>
   <tag3>value</tag3>
</root>
```

Вопрос. Как сделать чтобы мы могли задать атрибут с любым номером

Встроенный генератор выдал какую то кашу

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class root
{

    private rootTag[] tagField;

    private string tag3Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("tag")]
    public rootTag[] tag
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tagField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tagField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string tag3
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tag3Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tag3Field = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class rootTag
{

    private string atr1Field;

    private string atr2Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string atr1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.atr1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.atr1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string atr2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.atr2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.atr2Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как создать класс для данного xml - вот вопрос.

Comment: Структура вашего `xml` довольно странная, у вас нет возможности её изменить?

Comment: В этом и суть - десериализовать такой xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> если их будет больше и с другими id

Если число в именах атрибутов и элементов является `id`, то нужно пересмотреть саму схему формирования xml. Делать как-то так:

```
<tag id="1" atr="value"/>
<tag id="2" atr="value"/>
```

Или так, если содержимое является сложным:

```
<tag id="1">complex value</tag>
<tag id="2">complex value</tag>
```

Для такого xml набор классов C# получается простым и логичным.

---

Пожалуй, проще всего использовать следующий класс:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Attr { get; set; }
}
```

и разбирать xml с помощью linq:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

// Выбираем все элементы, начинающиеся с tag
var tagElements = xml.Elements()
    .Where(elem => elem.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("tag"));

// Создаём список объектов класса Tag, свойство Attr которого
// будет заполнено значением атрибута atr{n} или равно null
var tags = tagElements.Select(elem => new Tag
{
    Attr = elem.Attributes()
        .FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("atr"))?.Value
})
.ToList();
```

Обратите внимание на использование [null-conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn986595.aspx) оператора `?.` (его ещё называют Элвис).

---

Если всё же очень хочется использовать десериализацию, то есть несколько разных способов: реализовать интерфейс `IXmlSerializable`, написать кастомный `XmlReader` или использовать события самого сериализатора.

Покажу, как применить последний подход.

Набор классов может быть разный. Например, создадим такой:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("tag")]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [XmlAttribute("atr")]
    public string Attr { get; set; }
}
```

При создании сериализатора подпишем его на события:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
xs.UnknownElement += Xs_UnknownElement;
xs.UnknownAttribute += Xs_UnknownAttribute;
```

Эти события возникают, когда в xml встречаются неизвестные элементы и атрибуты. В коде обработчиков этих событий вручную читаем значения элементов или узлов и записываем их в наши экземпляры объектов.

```
private static void Xs_UnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e)
{
    Tag tag = (Tag)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    tag.Attr = e.Attr.Value;
}

private static void Xs_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    Root root = (Root)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
    Tag tag = new Tag();
    tag.Attr = e.Element.InnerText;
    root.Tags.Add(tag);
}
```

Использование как обычно:

```
Root root;

using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    root = (Root)xs.Deserialize(fs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что нельзя через стандартный десериализатор это сделать, так как XML накладывается на конкретный класс, который будет содержать значения XML.

Поэтому, на мой взгляд, есть 2 варианта:

1. Через Reader читать узлы заполнять объект, как вам хочется.
2. Написать собственный десериализатор.